# Zip.Save(Response.OutputStream) Error

Tags: c#, zip, iconic

Hi i have downloaded the dll files needed for Zip downloading. I have succesfully downloaded multiple pdf files on server directory and i wrote the code for zip thos multiple files and provide download ption to client , But from n number of pdf file the last 'n' number file is missing from below path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\11.0
and this exception of file not found was throwned on 
zip.Save(Response.OutputStream) --Code Line. Any type of help is appreciated.

```
protected void Btn_DownloadZip_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/EStatement/"));
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
            }//Collecting names of file from specified Path

            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
                zip.AddDirectoryByName("Zip_Statements");

                for(int i=0;i<files.Count;i++)
                {
                    string FPtoAdd = files[i].Text;
                    zip.AddFile(FPtoAdd, "Zip_Statements");
                }

                Response.Clear();
                Response.BufferOutput = false;
                string ZipName = string.Format("Zip_{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss"));
                Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ZipName);
                zip.Save(Response.OutputStream); //ERROR LINE
                Response.End();

          }

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogging.SendErrorToText(Ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the output.Mini mistake was that i am not giving the path for download in above code. thats why it is throwing exception.

string FPtoAdd = Server.MapPath("~/EStatement/") + "" + files[i].Text;

This thing do the work for Me. Thank you